# How can I remove a space only if it occurs in between two numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

In SQL Server I want to update a string in order to remove a space (or any given character) **only** if it occurs in between two numbers.

Input:

```
q 12 1 4 12422 test 1 testagain
```

Expected output:

```
q 121412422 test 1 testagain
```

Is there any elegant way to do so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create this function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[RemoveSpaceBetweenNumbers] (@str varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(max)
BEGIN

WHILE PATINDEX('%[0-9] [0-9]%',@str) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @str = STUFF(@str, PATINDEX('%[0-9] [0-9]%',@str)+1,1,'')
    END;

    RETURN @str;
END;
```

Then you can update your field like this:

```
UPDATE YourTable SET YourColumn=dbo.RemoveSpaceBetweenNumbers(YourColumn);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @str varchar(max)='q 12 1 4 12422 test 1 testagain'

declare @T table (item varchar(500) not null)
declare @d varchar(10)
set @d = ' '
declare @start int
declare @len int 
declare @pos int
declare @pos1 int
declare @val varchar(500)
set @pos = 1
Set @start = charindex(@d,@str,@pos)
Set @len = len(@str)
While @start <= @len
begin
    if (@pos = 1) 
    begin
        set @val = substring(@str,1,@start-1)
        insert into @T values(@val)
        set @pos = @pos + 1
    end
    else
    begin
        Set @pos1 = charindex(@d,@str,@start+1)
        if @pos1 = 0
        begin
                set @val = substring(@str,@start+1,@len-@start)
            insert into @T values(@val)
            break;
        end
        set @val = substring(@str,@start+1,@pos1-@start-1)
        insert into @T values(@val)
        set @start =    @pos1   
        set @pos1 = 0
    end
end


DECLARE @OUTPUT VARCHAR(MAX), @previtem varchar(500), @item varchar(500)

DECLARE CRS CURSOR FOR 
SELECT item FROM @T 

OPEN CRS 

FETCH NEXT FROM CRS INTO @previtem 
SET @OUTPUT=@previtem
WHILE (@@fetch_status = 0) 
BEGIN 
    FETCH NEXT FROM CRS INTO @item 
    IF (@item<>@previtem)
    BEGIN
        IF (ISNUMERIC(@item)=1 AND ISNUMERIC(@previtem)=1)
            SET @OUTPUT = @OUTPUT + @item
        ELSE 
            SET @OUTPUT = @OUTPUT + ' ' + @item
    END
    SET @previtem=@item
END 

CLOSE CRS 
DEALLOCATE CRS 

select @OUTPUT
select * from @T
```

Comment: output is : q 121412422 test 1 testagain

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. find a split method and build an array/table. And create a second array/table
2. iterate through 1 to n (base 0)
3. if each item is a number and the previous is a number merge them
4. Merge new array in a new string

I would do this in my application rather than T-SQL. It will be easier, simpler and shorter path to go.

Comment: Thanks but I can do this only using SQL

Comment: OK - I will try to help

Comment: Added as new full answer - Good luck